# python queue.join() dosen't work

Tags: python, multithreading, join, queue

I'm trying to do a multiprocessing computation in python but from some reason i can't control the number of new created processes. after few seconds the IDE is getting crushed under hundreds of new processes. 
here is the problematic code (start with expectiEvaluation at the bottom):

```
   def serialExpecti(state, level):
    allPieces = [L(), T(), O(), Z(), I(), J(), S()]
    if level == 0:
        return expectiHelper(state) / len(allPieces)

    queueStates = util.PriorityQueueWithFunction(expectiHelper)
    evaluation = 0;
    for i in range(len(allPieces)):
        succsecors = findAllPossiblePositions(state, allPieces[i])
        for curState in succsecors:
            queueStates.push(curState)
        bestState = queueStates.pop() 
        evaluation += serialExpecti(bestState, level + 1)
        queueStates = util.PriorityQueueWithFunction(expectiHelper)  # clear queue   
#     print  evaluation  
    return evaluation   

def parallelExpecti(state, queue):
    print os.getpid()
    queue.put(serialExpecti(state, 0))



def expectiEvaluation(state):
     allPieces = [L(), T(), O(), Z(), I(), J(), S()]
     queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
     queueStates = util.PriorityQueueWithFunction(expectiHelper)
     for i in range(len(allPieces)):
         succsecors = findAllPossiblePositions(state, allPieces[i])  
         for curState in succsecors:
            queueStates.push(curState)
         bestState = queueStates.pop()
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=parallelExpecti, args=(bestState, queue,))
         p.start()
     queue.join()
     evaluation = 0;
     while not queue.empty():
         evaluation += queue.get()
     return evaluation
```

the computation in serialExpecti() is very heavy so i wanted to make it parallel. 
the function expectiEvaluation() is being called from the main thread many times during the run of the program, and i think that from some reason the queue.join() doesn't block the execution so that the main thread keeps ruining and calling expectiEvaluation() causing it to create more and more processes.
what could be the problem?

**UPDATE:** 
I tried to get rid of the queue.join() by just keeping all the processes in a list and joining them at the end of the the function and it worked...sort of. now the processes are under control and not being created like crazy, but the programme is running very very slow. much much slower then the pure serial version. what am i doing wrong?
maybe it will help if i put here the serial version:

```
 def expectiHelper(state):
    return 10*holesEvaluation(state) + fullRowEvaluation(state) +  heightEvaluation(state) + maxLengthEvaluation(state) + averageEvaluation(state)+ medianEvalutaion(state)

def expectiEvaluation(state, level=0):
    global problem
    allPieces=[L(), T(), O(), Z(),  I(),  J(),  S()]
    if level==3:
        return expectiHelper(state)/len(allPieces)

    queueStates = util.PriorityQueueWithFunction(expectiHelper)
    evaluation=0;
    for i in range(len(allPieces)):
        succsecors = problem.findAllPossiblePositions(state,allPieces[i])
        for curState in succsecors:
            queueStates.push(curState)
        bestState =  queueStates.pop() 
        evaluation+= expectiEvaluation(bestState, level+1)  #add best evaluation for this piece
        queueStates = util.PriorityQueueWithFunction(expectiHelper) #clear queue   
#     print  evaluation  
    return evaluation
```

as you can see it is a recursive function and every iteration in this loop is independent and very very heavy, so i it could be doen in parallel:

```
for i in range(len(allPieces)):
```

Comment: What is `serialExpecti`?

Comment: the first function in the code. look at the edit now.